# how to paging from top 99 rows in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

select *from 
   (select *from new_count_goods_details limit 99) 
sub limit 10 offset 90;

how to achieve the mysql statement by sqlalchemy?

this is my code:

```
    limit_subquery  = q.filter(StyleList.add_time >= yesterday_18).\
        filter(StyleList.add_time <= today_18).\
        order_by(StyleList.rank_num.desc()).\
        limit(99).\
        subquery("limit_subquery")
    q = limit_subquery.offset((p-1)*ps).limit(ps)
```

it is error code, error info:
AttributeError: 'Alias' object has no attribute 'offset'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select from subquery

```
q = session.query(limit_subquery).offset((p-1)*ps).limit(ps)
```